# postLoad entity with association without lazy load?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

This is my pb.

I have an entity game, and an entity console
It's a **ManyToMany** association.

For more performance, i load game and console in the same query like this :

```
$this->_em->getRepository('MyBundle:Console')
        ->createQueryBuilder('console')
        ->join('console.game', 'game')
        ->select('game', 'console')
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

When I use `$console->getGames()` that display all games without perform any query

When I use the **postLoad event**, every `$console->getGames()` perform query because the event start before the object is completely hydrated.

On doctrine website, I found this advise :

> "Note that, when using Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery#iterate(), postLoad
>   events will be executed immediately after objects are being hydrated,
>   and therefore associations are not guaranteed to be initialized. It is
>   not safe to combine usage of Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery#iterate() and
>   postLoad event handlers."

So, someone knows how use **postLoad event** with the complete hydrated Entity ? I don't want lazy load.

But it's not my case

Comment: It is not clear what is your question

Comment: Sry, I edited my post : 
So, someone knows how use postLoad event with the complete hydrated Entity ?

Comment: Start by adding ->select('console,game') to your query since, as it is currently written, your query is still lazy loading the games.  And then perhaps update your question with a question.

Comment: I forgot to add the select into the post but I have it into my project

Comment: It's just the way postLoad works.  You will have to loop through the results and send your own events.

Comment: No, it's not the way postLoad works. In doctrine 2.5 the relations are supposed to be hydrated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour has actually changed in Doctrine 2.5. From 2.5 all associations should be loaded in postLoad event. Doctrine 2.5 should fix your problem, reference:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/changelog/migration_2_5.html#events-postload-now-triggered-after-associations-are-loaded